# Align the legend and the title in the center of plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset and I want to plot the heat map for them. my problem is: I want a vertical legend and also I want to put the title of legend in the middle of legend.

My data is a text file with is like the attached figure.

[image: my data]

Here is the code that I am using( when I change the horizontal to the vertical, the legend moves up and also the title is not in the center of legend).

```
# Heatmap
ggplot(heat, aes(Samples, Gene, fill= log(Folded_Change_of_Expression))) +
  geom_tile()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+ theme(axis.text.y = 
 element_text(size = 12)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 4)+theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
   guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 5, barheight = 1, title = "log(Folded 
  Change of Expression)",
                            title.position = "top", direction = "horizontal"))
```

However, the output figure for me is not the thing that I want. Could you please help me with that?
Thank you[image]

Legend that I want is same as this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion:
New added last 3 lines remove existent guides lines:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(heat, aes(Samples, Gene, fill= log(Folded_Change_of_Expression))) +
  geom_tile()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 4)+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = "colourbar") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title.position = "right",
                             title = "log(Folded Change \n of Expression)"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, for me, the results is not the same as you. My legend moves up. 
Also, the label y is not correct.

Comment: My trick to overcome this was to use `\n` line break. But look at @jared_mamrot solution. this one is a very good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the only way to 'center' the colourbar and title is for the colourbar to be larger than the legend title, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

heat <- data.frame(Samples = rep(c(paste("Control", 1:10, sep = "_"),
                               paste("Treat", 1:10, sep = "_")), each = 2),
                   Gene = c("Occludin", "Claudin"),
                   Folded_Change_of_Expression = runif(20, -4, 4))

ggplot(heat, aes(x = Samples, y = Gene, fill = log(abs(Folded_Change_of_Expression)))) +
  geom_tile() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 4) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.box = "vertical",
        legend.title = element_text(angle = 90,
                                    hjust = 0.5,
                                    vjust = 0.5),
        legend.justification = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title = "log(Fold Change in Gene Expression)",
                                title.position = "right",
                                title.hjust = 0.5,
                                title.vjust = 0.5,
                                legend.title.align = 0.5,
                                barheight = 14))
```

[image]

When the legend title is longer than the colourbar it appears to 'fall back' on a default justification. I've had a look at the source code for guide_colourbar (https://rdrr.io/github/SahaRahul/ggplot2/src/R/guide-colorbar.r) but it's not clear to me why this is the case. If you make the legend title smaller, it is positioned as expected:

```r
library(tidyverse)

heat <- data.frame(Samples = rep(c(paste("Control", 1:10, sep = "_"),
                               paste("Treat", 1:10, sep = "_")), each = 2),
                   Gene = c("Occludin", "Claudin"),
                   Folded_Change_of_Expression = runif(20, -4, 4))

ggplot(heat, aes(x = Samples, y = Gene, fill = log(abs(Folded_Change_of_Expression)))) +
  geom_tile() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 4) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.box = "vertical",
        legend.title = element_text(angle = 90,
                                    hjust = 0,
                                    vjust = 0,
                                    size = 8),
        legend.justification = c(0, 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title = "log(Fold Change in Gene Expression)",
                                title.position = "right",
                                title.vjust = 0.5,
                                barheight = 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: not on a computer right now but why do you use different vjust/ hjust for legend.title in your examples and have you tried to set hjust to .5 in a “longer title”?

Comment: Hi @tjebo, I think I tried almost every combination of 'just' settings to see whether I could get the desired effect. When the angle of the title isn't 90 degrees (i.e. when it's horizontal) the hjust/vjust works as expected (0.5 is the middle of the legend) but when the title is vertical and larger than the colorbar it causes OP's problem. The other workaround I looked at was the margin (e.g. `title.theme = element_text(angle = 90, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = -70, l = 0, unit = "pt"))))`) and I got close but I also wasn't able to get the colorbar and text aligned properly.